# Getting "undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass" in integration test for OmniAuth

Tags: rspec, omniauth

I have Omniauth test mode on:

**spec_helper (I put it at the bottom of the file, right before `end`):**

```
#Turn on "test mode" for OmniAuth 
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
```

and this is my test:

**spec/request/authorization_pages_spec.rb:**

```
 describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }
    .
    .
    .
    describe "with OmniAuth" do
      before do
        OmniAuth.config.add_mock :facebook, uid: "fb-12345", info: { name: "Bob Smith" }
        visit root_path
      end

      describe "Facebook provider" do
        before do
          request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]
          click_link "Sign in with Facebook"
        end

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

        it { should have_link('Users',    href: users_path) }
        it { should have_link('Profile',  href: user_path(user)) }
        it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
        it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }

        it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
      end
```

when I run my test I get this:

Failures:

```
  1) Authentication signin with OmniAuth Facebook provider 
     Failure/Error: request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:57:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

(etc).

Is there something missing or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem....

Comment: @Brandon After two weeks without sleep, I gave up. And adopted a new rule: never test gems, or you'll end up hating testing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mixing two different things in this example. You're trying to write an integration spec but the `request` method AFAIK is available only in the controllers specs (for specs inside `spec/controllers` directory). Therefore you have `undefined method`env' for nil:NilClass` error.

You could find healthy OmniAuth integration spec in my sample project: https://github.com/lucassus/locomotive/blob/9cd7dfd365469fc70fc367f29705a56df9730f6f/spec/features/user_facebook_sign_in_spec.rb

I hope it would help you.

Comment: Isn't that a feature spec, rather than a request spec?